# Changing global stack size, GNU Prolog

Tags: prolog, stack, global, gnu-prolog

So I'm working with GNU Prolog on a bash server at my university and I need to increase the global stack size.

I've tried compiling with the following options:

```
    gprolog --global-size 16384 --init-goal 'consult('test')'
```

where test is just a test.pl file I made for testing.  However, I still get the following exception

```
    Fatal Error: global stack overflow (size: 8192 Kb, environment variable used: GLOBALSZ)
```

Which indicates that the size is still 8192 Kb.  Unfortunately I'm running GNU Prolog version 1.2.16 as that's what's on the server and I can't readily change it.  Is there anything I can do here?

Comment: It says it used GLOBALSZ to set the stack size from the environment, did you try setting that?

Comment: Apparently setting this option should overwrite environmental variables.  From the gnuprolog manual: http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog008.html

Answer (score 2):

Try:
GLOBALSZ=16384 gprolog --init-goal 'consult('test')'